# Ember not persisting belongsTo data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am using Ember 2.4.6 and JSONApiAdapter of Ember for getting and sending data to the node servers.

I have the following Tags model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  label: DS.attr('string'),
  isRoot: DS.attr('boolean', {defaultValue: false'}),
  parent: DS.belongsTo('tag') //belongs to self type
});
```

The logic here is that a user can enter multiple sub tags for a given root tag. And to save the sub tags and the root tags I am using a save method from tag service. The save method from tag service is as below

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({

  //Some other code

  save: function(parent, children){
    return parent.save().then(response => {
      return children.map(tag => {
        tag.set('parent', response);
        return tag.save();
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Now the problem here is that when I have say five subtags for the root tag, then the relationship is getting persisted only for the last tag i.e. the fifth tag.

I have created five tags say `one`, `two`, `three`, `four` and `five` for the `root` parent tag. Then when the save method is called from the tag service then ideally the following data should be going to the servers.

```
{data: {id: 1, type: 'tags', attributes: {label: "root", "is-root": true}, relationships: {parent: {data: null}}}}
{data: {id: 2, type: 'tags', attributes: {label: "one", "is-root": false}, relationships: {parent: {data: {id: 1, type: "tags"}}}}}
{data: {id: 3, type: 'tags', attributes: {label: "two", "is-root": false}, relationships: {parent: {data: {id: 1, type: "tags"}}}}}
{data: {id: 4, type: 'tags', attributes: {label: "three", "is-root": false}, relationships: {parent: {data: {id: 1, type: "tags"}}}}}
{data: {id: 5, type: 'tags', attributes: {label: "four", "is-root": false}, relationships: {parent: {data: {id: 1, type: "tags"}}}}}
{data: {id: 6, type: 'tags', attributes: {label: "five", "is-root": false}, relationships: {parent: {data: {id: 1, type: "tags"}}}}}
```

but instead the following information is going to the server

```
{data: {id: 1, type: 'tags', attributes: {label: "root", "is-root": true}, relationships: {parent: {data: null}}}}
{data: {id: 2, type: 'tags', attributes: {label: "one", "is-root": false}, relationships: {parent: {data: null}}}}
{data: {id: 3, type: 'tags', attributes: {label: "two", "is-root": false}, relationships: {parent: {data: null}}}}
{data: {id: 4, type: 'tags', attributes: {label: "three", "is-root": false}, relationships: {parent: {data: null}}}}
{data: {id: 5, type: 'tags', attributes: {label: "four", "is-root": false}, relationships: {parent: {data: null}}}}
{data: {id: 6, type: 'tags', attributes: {label: "five", "is-root": false}, relationships: {parent: {data: {id: 1, type: "tags"}}}}}
```

The belongsTo information is only being sent for the last tag, and for all the other tags, the parent data is getting missed.

Not able to exactly understand why this is happening. Please suggest what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Is your model a `tag` type or `userfield` type? It seems to change between the model definition and the sample data

Comment: @Beno thanks, for pointing out, corrected the question

Comment: Your repo doesn't have quite the same content in it

Comment: @JonRed,  yep modified some code after I raised the question in the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Tags model, try this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  label: DS.attr('string'),
  isRoot: DS.attr('boolean', {defaultValue: false}),
  parent: DS.belongsTo('tag', {inverse: null})
});
```

You can get more information about reflexive relationships here: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/models/relationships/#toc_reflexive-relations

From the page:

> When you want to define a reflexive relation (a model that has a
>   relationship to itself), you must explicitly define the inverse
>   relationship. If there is no inverse relationship then you can set the
>   inverse to null.